# Preassigned Variable is Corrupted During Exception Handling in PHP

Tags: php, exception, assign

The variable $maxTry is unassigned when an exception is raised and

the exception handling stops at nTry = 1.

How is this possible?

```
$nTry=0;
$maxTry=100;
function verify() { 
  try{
      // Some DB Connection
      $st = $dbh->prepare(...);
      $result = $st->fetchColumn();
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
    $nTry++;
    echo 'PDOException<br/>';
    if($e->getCode()==='HY000') {
        echo 'verify again<br/>';
        if($nTry < $maxTry) {
            $maxTry=100;
            verify();      //recursion
        }
        else 
            echo "Reached maxTry ($nTry __ $maxTry) PDOException: HY000<br/>";
    }
}
verify();
```

Expected output (if reached maxTry):

```
PDOException
verify again
...
verify again
Reached max try (100 __ 100) PDOException: HY000
```

Actual output ($maxTry is not set):

```
PDOException
verify again
Reached max try (1 __ ) PDOException: HY000
```

Comment: Your scoping is wrong. `$maxTry` doesn't exist in the `verify` functions scope (until after you try using it).

Comment: Simple scope issue  -the variables are not accessible inside the function

Comment: confused with javascript scope. Not raising any error message when incrementing $nTry made it even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the variables in a function, but declaring them outside, they are not accessible.  You need to add this right after the the opening of the function.

```
function verify() { 
    global $maxTry, $nTry; // add this
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables are out of scope, instead have them passed as parameters:

```
function verify($nTry, $maxTry)
{
    try {
        // Some DB Connection
        $st = $dbh->prepare(...);
        $result = $st->fetchColumn();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $nTry++;
        echo 'PDOException<br/>';
        if ($e->getCode() === 'HY000') {
            echo 'verify again<br/>';
            if ($nTry < $maxTry) {
                verify($nTry, $maxTry);      //recursion
            } else
                echo "Reached maxTry ($nTry __ $maxTry) PDOException: HY000<br/>";
        }
    }
}
varify(0, 100);
```